# cancel password of svn list

Tags: linux, svn, command-line-interface, solaris

how I can cancel the password of svn list. When I execute svn list it is Requests the password twice. I need to execute it without password.

Comment: do you have direct access to the host on which your svn repositorys reside ?

Comment: i need anything to cancel password and i i can direct access  ..why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are trying to use one of the files you have created based on answers to other questions. If you are trying to run commands of the form

```
svn list svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core
```

If that's correct then log on to svn.xxx.com.jo and run the commands like this

```
svn list file:///var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core
```